in csh terminal gvim -d is sourcing .cshrc file
In csh shell, whenever I am doing gvim -d it is sourcing .cshrc file.
I tried passing -f option. It is not working.
I tried solution suggested in:
How to disable vim source .cshrc when running external command?
It is still not working.
Kindly help.

What exact problem do you have? First, just running gvim should not source any shell configuration init scripts, but it may need to, when you run external commands. So you may want to configure the various 'shell' properties.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Vim :-) If you could give us the exact shell command that you are using to start gVim, the action that you are executing within Vim and the symptom that makes you believe the .cshrc file is sourced we would be in a much better position to reproduce your problem and provide you guidance :-)
